# UIWebView not loading data sometime in iOS 9

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, wkwebview

UIWebView not loading (mobile web page) **sometime** in iOS 9. I already used ATS bypass using **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads**.The issues not happening always and works well in iOS 7 and 8.
     The delegate method webViewDidStartLoad invoked but webViewDidFinishLoad and didFailLoadWithError is not getting called at all.

Comment: For iOS 9 you can use Safari View Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.All you need to do is **remove UIWebView in iOS 9 and use WKWebView**.My webpage had some third party calls to twitter,instagram etc which is https.Also I was getting Auth challenge in my webpage..! *(Even I disabled the ATS)*.I found this by using WKWebView,which has the delegate to handle auth challenge.

Set the below delegate to get the auth challenge and handle it.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler

{
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    CFDataRef exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(serverTrust);
    SecTrustSetExceptions(serverTrust, exceptions);
    CFRelease(exceptions);

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,
                      [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);

}
```